# Sum rows in one column between 2 time range

Tags: excel, formula

Is there a way to sum values in a column between two different time. The two different hrs are different for different start and end calculation. The formula i used is `=SUMIFS(Period,time,">="&Time Range,time,  Range,"<="&Time Range)` , but the formula returns only the first hour value but the expected result should be between total of start calc and end cal value

```
time          period  Cal stat    Time Range       Expected Result
6:37:02 AM      1     start calc  6:37:02 AM     4
6:37:03 AM      1     no action     0   
6:37:04 AM      2     End Calc    6:37:04 AM
6:37:06 AM      1     Start Calc  6:37:06 AM     6
6:37:07 AM      1     no action     0 
6:37:08 AM      2     no action     0
6:37:10 AM      1     no action     0
6:37:11 AM      1     End Calc    6:37:11 AM
6:37:12 AM      2     Start Calc   6:37:12 AM     3
6:37:14 AM      1     End Calc     6:37:14 AM 
6:37:15 AM      1     no action     0    
6:37:16 AM      1     no action     0
6:37:17 AM      2     no action     0
6:37:19 AM      2     no action     0
```

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to StackOverflow.. If those columns are "A:E" and the table has headers in First Row ("A1:E1") .. In "Expected Result" (E Column) , in E2 formula  `=IF(C2="End Calc",B2,E3+B2)`  and copy it down. Totals will be on the "Start Calc" Rows. You can then copy paste the values, filter "Cal stat" Column for not equal to "Start Calc" and delete the expected results. Remove the filter and you will see remaining results at the start calc rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about doing it with `SUMIFS`.

However, with `INDEX(MATCH(…`, you can construct a formula that will sum from the current row to the **next** `"end Calc"`, and use an `IF(…` to only show results in the `start calc` rows.

```
E2: =IF(C2="start calc", SUM( INDEX(B2:$B$15,1):  INDEX(B2:$B$15,MATCH(TRUE,C2:$C$15="end Calc",0))),"")
```

- Fill the formula down as far as needed
- The `$15` row numbers in the formula can be changed to any row that is at least as large as your expected table, but be sure it remains an absolute address.

  - e.g: `=IF(C2="start calc", SUM( INDEX(B2:$B$1500,1):  INDEX(B2:$B$1500,MATCH(TRUE,C2:$C$1500="end Calc",0))),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron. this is is what I'm looking for. However, using the formula i'm getting #N/A. I even copied and past your formula. still the same result. What am i missing ? this is my formula                                                            =IF(C2="start calc", SUM( INDEX(B2:$B$145000,1): INDEX(B2:$B$145000,MATCH(TRUE,C2:$C$145000="end Calc",0))),"")

Comment: @mily Perhaps with your version of Excel, you will need to confirm the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` as an array formula.

Comment: Great! I added an array formula. It worked perfectly. I'm using Excel 365.. Thank you so much Ron for your help and quick response!